# what the output of this code and why?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I want to ask if is it possible that this code will print 190?

the father pid =9 
the child pid = 10
.
.
.

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid<0)
{ 
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid>0)
{
    printf("%d",getpid());
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    char *const argv[] = {"sleep","1",NULL};
    execv("/bin/sleep", argv);
    printf("%d",getpid());
}
```

Comment: `exit)0(`? Make sure to check your typing before you post.

Comment: What is the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I don't think that's the point.  The question seems to be whether the parent's and child's outputs from one `printf()` call each can be intermingled.

Comment: the question is what will be the output on screen if the execv failed

Comment: So what purpose does it serve to include the `execv()` call in your example code?  What difference are you supposing it might make for `execv()` to fail vs. not being called at all?

Comment: i suppose to know what all the outputs of the code ... so there 3 ways first if the fork did not work ... second if fork work and execv worked... third if fork worked and execv did not worked, so my question is if the fork worked(did not failed) and execv failed is it possible to print 190 to my screen ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it and forced the execv() to fail?

Comment: Since this is apparently homework, it seems reasonable to presume that you are expected to rely on information presented in class and in out-of-class course resources such as a textbook.  What do these have to say about it?

Comment: mom is that you !!!? and no it's not homework ...

Comment: coursework?   The thing is, your question does not track as anything else but a homework question.  If it was a real issue, with a real app, you could have used an explicit lock, or flock/funlock, or whatever mutex was available, to enforce line-by-line output.  As it stands, it's very difficult to see your question as anything but an academic exercise of next-to-no use to future SO users.

Comment: ..and I'm guessing that you did not try it yourself, preferring to leave teh actual work of testing to SO users.  'what the output of this code' gave me my first clue.

Comment: the call to `execv()` will not return unless the call fails.  Then the code should be calling `perror()` and `exit()` not trying to print the PID value

Comment: the parent process, is creating a child process.  The parent process should not exit until the child process exits.  This can be accomplished by calling `int status;, waitpid( pid, &status, 0 )'` in the parent

Answer (score 0):

it is very unlikely that the child pid would be such a low number as 190, although it is possible.

It is virtually impossible that the parent pid would be 9 and the child pid would be 10 because the boot of the system would be generating larger pid values than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the child, if execv succeeds, it will never return. This causes the printf() to not be executed. "190" you see is only from the parent printing its own pid.